# INDIRECT parameter value is not a valid in another tab

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I create an [account sheet on a google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wSpAiNm_BpWzT5B7tozMFXLcSLFDBZyh0zxrR_bQSqY/edit?usp=sharing) for my new small business. There have 3 tab sheets. In the Dec tab, I want to create a dependable dropdown list. *In the **data tab**, the Array Formula works correctly but the same formula does work in **Dec Tab***. Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(D2:D), TRANSPOSE(
 IF(TRANSPOSE(D2:D)=Data!B1, INDIRECT("Data!Funding"),
 IF(TRANSPOSE(D2:D)=Data!C1, INDIRECT("Data!Sales_Revenue"),
 IF(TRANSPOSE(D2:D)=Data!D1, INDIRECT("Data!Space_Equipment"),
 INDIRECT("Data!Inventory_Purchase"))))), ))
```

[image]